# JQ: how to add attributes to input

Tags: jquery

I have input:

```
<input id="id_fromDate" type="text">
```

Need to get:

```
<input class="form-control" id="id_fromDate" type="text" datepicker data-date-format="yyyy.mm.dd" data-week-start="1" data-auto-close="true">
```

I can add class to this input:
$("#id_fromDate").addClass("form-control")

But how to add attributes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding attrbute use

```
.attr("attrName", "value");
```

method of Jquery.

For adding multiple attributes as in your case use

```
$("#id_fromDate").attr({
    data-date-format : 'yyyy.mm.dd',
    data-week-start : '1',
    data-auto-close: 'true'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("#id_fromDate").attr("attribute-name", "some-value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `attr()`:

```
$("#id_fromDate").attr("new-attribute","value")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use attr(name, value)

```
$("#id_fromDate").attr("placeholder", "Please input date");
```

To remove attr, use removeAttr(name)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think just adding the attributes will solve your problem... the said attributes are used initialize the datepicker plugin.. so instead of adding the attributes, initialize the plugin like

```
$("#id_fromDate").addClass("form-control").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy.mm.dd',
    weekStart: 1,
    autoClose: true
})
```